# Android Bitmap image upload to mysql database as a blob data type

Tags: mysqli

Bimap image not uplaod at server. in database image table have a blob data type attribute. i want to save bitmap image in database

```
 class savebitmap extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

     try {
         // Save the image to the SD card.
        //File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
        //System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
        //FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        //bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

        //convert to byte

        ByteArrayOutputStream bytedata = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytedata);
        byte[] data = bytedata.toByteArray();
        String imagedata = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
        String name="prescription";
        //save image to mysql


        httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        httppost= new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/android/image.php"); 
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",name));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",imagedata)); 
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        response=httpclient.execute(httppost);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();            

        InputStream is = entity.getContent();

        Log.e("Connection", "connection success ");
        Log.e("bitmap", imagedata);

     } catch (Exception e) {
         Log.e("upload failed", e.toString());
     }



    return null;
 }
 }
```

My php file which recive the data from http request and insert into database

```
   <?php


  mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die (mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db("image") or die (mysql_errno());


 $base= $_REQUEST['image'];
 $name= $_REQUEST['name'];
 $buffer = base64_decode($base);
 $buffer = mysql_real_escape_string($buffer);

$flag['code']=0;

if($q=mysql_query("INSERT INTO image ('name','image')
  VALUES ('$name',$buffer')"))
{
$flag['code']=1;
```

}

```
print(json_encode($flag));

mysql_close(); 
mysql_close();
```

?>

Logcat

09-12 19:07:43.486: D/dalvikvm(816): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 5% free 6131K/6388K, paused 44ms, total 44ms
09-12 19:07:43.666: D/gralloc_goldfish(816): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
09-12 19:07:46.946: D/dalvikvm(816): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2507K, 43% free 3651K/6388K, paused 68ms, total 69ms
09-12 19:07:46.946: I/dalvikvm-heap(816): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.974MB for 1334416-byte allocation
09-12 19:07:46.986: D/dalvikvm(816): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 23% free 4952K/6388K, paused 7ms+3ms, total 37ms
09-12 19:07:46.986: D/dalvikvm(816): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 17ms
09-12 19:07:49.766: D/dalvikvm(816): GC_CONCURRENT freed 577K, 20% free 5124K/6388K, paused 4ms+7ms, total 44ms
09-12 19:07:50.946: E/Connection(816): connection success

Comment: You forgot the part where you ask a question.  Is this code failing in some way?  Are you getting an error?  Unexpected behavior?  What are you asking?  (Also, please be aware that you have a wide open ***SQL injection vulnerability*** in your code.  You also have a syntax error in your SQL statement, which I'm sure the database is telling you about in an error message.  You also try to close the database twice, which probably results in another error.)

Comment: dear mybitmap image which converted into byte array not upload at the server side ?

Comment: there is no error in making a connection

Comment: Are you sure it's not being uploaded at all?  What debugging have you done to confirm this?  Is the failure occurring client-side or server-side?  When you debug this, where specifically does it fail?  What information do you have about that failure?

Comment: yeah m sure image file is not uploaded at server side in try catch block its show a connection success log

Comment: i think there is error in my php file are you help me in that

Comment: If your client-side code shows success, that would imply that the image *is* being uploaded to the server-side code, and that the error is happening server-side.  (Which makes the client-side code irrelevant.)  Again, you need to narrow down the problem.  Just telling us that "it doesn't work" isn't a problem statement.  Debugging tools are your friends.

Answer (score -1):

You have an error in your SQL syntax:

```
INSERT INTO image ('name','image') VALUES ('$name',$buffer')
```

Note that you're missing an opening quote on your second parameter.  It should be:

```
INSERT INTO image ('name','image') VALUES ('$name','$buffer')
                                                   ^--- right there
```

You're also trying to close the connection twice for some reason:

```
mysql_close(); 
mysql_close();
```

There's a pretty good chance that would result in an error.  Additionally, you're never examining the result of your SQL query or any error condition resulting from it.  You check for errors when *connecting* to the database, but not when *interacting* with it.  So there's a very good chance that the database is telling you *exactly what's wrong* and you're simply *ignoring it*.  When something isn't behaving as expected, it's a good idea to take a look at the errors first.

Also, and ***this is important***, your code is ***wide open to SQL injection attacks***.  You'll want to start by reading [this](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).  It will help you understand what a SQL injection attack is and how to protect your code from one.  In short, you are *executing user input as if it were code*.  This allows *any user* to execute *any code* on your server without your permission, which is clearly a very bad thing.

Comment: @awaiskhansar: As with the comments on the question, *what is that result*?  Nobody here can debug your code for you.  You need to determine exactly *how* it is failing.